# Spring MVC not loading resources

Tags: javascript, tomcat7, spring-4, http-status-code-405, jdk1.7

This is really frustrating I would appreciate some help with this as I have a deployment on coming weekend and suddenly the application has stopped working.
I have a Spring 4.3.3 application hosted on Apache Tomcat 7 with JDK 1.7. The application was running fine when it suddenly stopped loading all the JS, CSS and image files with an HTTP Status code of 405 (Get Method not allowed). The only noticeable change that I did was update the Java installed on my laptop. I have even uninstalled that version of java but no benefit.

The network tab of chrome shows the following result.

[image]

The error shown in Chrome browser is given below:

```
General:
    Request URL:http://localhost:8080/TractivityPhase3/resources/ui/jquery-ui.css
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
    Remote Address:[::1]:8080
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers:
    view source
    Allow:POST
    Content-Length:96
    Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
    Date:Mon, 10 Jul 2017 12:12:49 GMT
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headers:
    view source
    Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Connection:keep-alive
    Cookie:JSESSIONID=8F5257A38E3AC1FBBD4BCF0A869A5A05
    Host:localhost:8080
    Referer:http://localhost:8080/TractivityPhase3/login
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

My web.xml code is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>createIdeaPublic</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <display-name>Tractivity</display-name>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Tractivity</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Tractivity</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <listener>
        <listener-class>com.soft.utils.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
   <error-page>
    <location>/jsp/components/jspError.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

The dispatcher-Servlet configuration is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.soft.controllers, com.soft.ajax,com.soft.services, com.soft.daos" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/templates/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/ui/**" location="/resources/ui/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/" />
    <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/ui/**" location="/resources/ui/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/" /> -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <!-- 
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean> -->

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.soft.utils.SecureDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
         <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>


    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties, security.properties"/>

   <!--  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
         setting maximum upload size
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="emailer" class="com.soft.utils.Emailer">
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="from" value="CIActivityTracker@abc.com"/>
        <property name="username" value="368649312300d9094a62" />
        <property name="password" value="cbe8181247b9785036ee" />    

    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapContextSource" class="com.soft.utils.LdapContextSource">
        <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}"/>
        <property name="base" value="${ldap.base}"/>
        <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.userDn}"/>
        <property name="pass" value="${ldap.password}"/>
        <property name="referral" value="follow"/>
        <property name="ldapAuthentication" value="${ldap.authentication}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="logAspect" class="com.soft.aspect.LoggingAspect" />


    <bean id="simpleJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="quartzExample" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="printMessage" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="quartzExample" class="com.soft.quartz.QuartzExample">
        <property name="dbcViewName" value="${dbc.view}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dailyTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/2 * * * ? *" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="weeklyTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/6 * * ? * L *" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="monthlyTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/6 * * L * ? *" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="quarterlyTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/1 * * L MAR,JUN,SEP,DEC ? *" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="annualTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="simpleJobDetail" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/1 * * 31 12 ? *" />
    </bean>

    <bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
<!--                <ref bean="dailyTrigger" /> -->
                <ref bean="dailyTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**EDIT:**
I have temporarliy fixed the issue by adding the following to web.xml. However, I would like a clean way of handling it through the Dispatcher Servlet's  tag.

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.PNG</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Your resources is currently handled by dispatcher servlet that'why it is showing error, change your resourcemapping to `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/ui/**" location="/resources/ui/" /> `

Comment: I have already that code but instead of location set to "/resources/ui/", I want the location set to "/resources/ui/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/". So that if in future, I upgrade JQuery I would just change this line.